# How to pass XML data to web page running in web browser control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have windows application in which web page is loaded using the windows (.NET) browser control. The windows application needs to send some information to the web page (aspx) and now it's achieved using query string.

Now we want to send more details which may be in the XML format.

How can we pass the large amount of data (like XML) in such case?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *send* (more) data, you should use method POST. (That way you don't really need to care whether it's XML or something as long as the particular form can handle it correctly.)

Query string should be used only to *specify the resource*.  Typically query string is used with GET method like `http://server/giveme.php?report&number=123`.  (If that string is used with browser, it should open connection to `server:80` and say `GET /giveme.php?report&number=123`. (Then some headers follow, etc.)

Use of POST is very similar except that after the method, URI (`/hereis.php?report&number=124`) and some HTTP headers, also data is sent (which can really be any data).

Also remember that GET is supposed to be used only for queries: you can call `GET /giveme.php?report&number=123` a thousand times and you should still get *the same* report no. 123 (or some updated version). (So GET should not be used to send data, but to *get* data.)

For POST, this is not expected: Each time POST from you is accepted, you actually *post some data* to the server, and normally you should not get away with doing `POST /hereis.php?report&number=124` multiple times.  (Well, you can design your application to accept `POST /hereis.php?report`, but that's up to you and it's another story.)